# How to add ComboBox to specific columns on Binding DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a data grid view where on click event i have added combo box to particular columns. After selecting one of the value from combo box, i save it in db and it gets saved successfully. Now, when I load data grid view, which contains data from database, again i need those columns as combo box, so that when i click on save without changing values of combo box columns i do not get error.

What I have already tried is adding combo box on data grid view click event.

Any idea, how to make add combo box to specific columns when I bind data to data grid view?

Comment: You wanna add the data to your combobox?

Comment: data is present and i have saved it in db as well. Issue comes when I retrieve the data from database and want to show that data in combo box.